# C++: How to return abstract class in a method of this abstract class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have an abstract class and it has two derived classes. I'm trying to overload operator+ in the base class so I could do derivedClass=derivedClass+differentDerivedClass like this:

```
class iMatrix{
iMatrix operator+(const iMatrix& obj)
}

class UsualMatrix : public iMatrix

class SparseMatrix : public iMatrix
```

Inside of main, I want to do

```
SparseMatrix a, b;
UsualMatrix c=a+b;
```

I have copy constructors and everything that may be helpful. Now if I create the function like

```
iMatrix operator+(const iMatrix& obj)
```

Compiler (LLVM in Xcode) says "Return type 'iMatrix' is an abstract class", but theoretically everything else should work properly. I've read manuals and other StackOverflow threads, so I've tried this:

```
iMatrix& operator+(const iMatrix& obj)
```

Whereas function on its own does "add obj to this" and returns *this. The problem is when I do c=a+b, a becomes equal to c, but it should not be changed.

```
a=
1 1 
1 1 
b=
1 1 
1 1 
a+b=c; 
c=
2 2 
2 2 
b=
1 1 
1 1 
a=
2 2 
2 2
```

What should I do? Addition and multiplying must be implemented inside of base class, and I have no idea how to fix this error. 
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Polymorphism and value semantics don't do well together.

Comment: Do you really need an abstract type to represent matrices?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, because it's a university task to teach us abstract classes and stuff :)

Comment: OK, so maybe it is supposed to be a counter example. You already found one issue with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be a **non-member** function like this:

```
template <
  typename T,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<iMatrix, T>::value>::type
>
T operator+(T const & a, T const & b) {
   T res; 
   // calculate res
   return res;
}
```

Because `iMatrix` is an abstract class, you can not return an instance of it. In the example above we are overloading `operator+` for all derived classes `T` of `iMatrix` and we can return `T` instances.

Comment: It seems like neat solution for me, but produces the same error: "Overloaded 'operator+' must be a unary or binary operator (has 3 parameters)"

Comment: Don't write it as a member function :-) @JonathanX64

Comment: This kind of kills the runtime polymorphism, no?

Comment: @juanchopanza what should happen for `operator+(T const &, U const &)` ? when both `U` and `T` are derived classes?

Comment: @amin Exactly, what should happen?

Comment: That's my point, because `operator+` does only makes sense on same types we are not killing any runtime polymorphism :-) @juanchopanza

Comment: No, the "polymorphic" type could encapsulate the implementation. Your solution doesn't really fix OP's real problem. The real solution is more complex.

Comment: This should be the solution I'm looking for. 
I've written this function alongside iMatrix class (without properly implementing it just yet) and now it throws me two errors: "No viable conversion from 'typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<iMatrix, UsualMatrix>::value>::type' (aka 'void') to 'UsualMatrix'" from main and "Void function 'operator+' should not return a value" from here. ;(

Comment: @JonathanX64 This is not the solution you're looking for :-)

Comment: @JonathanX64 Sorry, tested and updated the solution :-)

Comment: @amin seems to work after I replaced "A" with "iMatrix" in your code; I'll implement calculation and will return back :)

Comment: @amin I've encountered one problem. I'm unable to do UsualMatrix+SparseMatrix using your solution, i.e. this doesn't work for different derived classes. How can we fix this?)

Comment: Well you can try overloading `operator+(U const &, T const &)`, and use a third parameter in template arguments to check that `U` is drived from `iMatrix` @JonathanX64

Comment: @JonathanX64 the main problem is "what the return type should be?"

Comment: @amin I successfully overloaded `T operator+(U const &, T const &)`. For some reason, program was crashing in the end, before returning 0 to terminal; I removed "delete a" from `~UsualMatrix{}` and now everything seems to be fine :) thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your intend design is the abstract return type.  Abstract classes can't be returned by value.  Only concrete classes can be returned by value.  So, to return abstract class you'd need a pointer or a reference.

Unfortunately, this will not work with the semantics of `operator+()` :

- either you'd return by reference the current object, and change it with the operation; but this is not compliant with the expected semantics, and furthermore might lead to wrong answerds (e.g. when doing `c = a+b+a+b;` )
- or you'd return the reference to a temporary object.  but this would be UB, because the temporaray object will decease when the function returns, making the reference irrelevant.
- finally `operator+` would not have a way to decide on its own of the concrete type to use for the return.  For example: `SparseMatrix a; UsualMatrix b;   a+b;` what should be the type to be used for the matrix a+b ?

You can use polymorphic and abstract types within operators, but not as a return type.  To implement this kind of things, you'd need to opt for your own set of operators, and letting the caller manage the temporary results manually:

```
UsualMatrix c,tmp; 
SparseMatrix a,b,x; 
...
a.add(b, tmp);
tmp.add(x, c);   // c = a+b+x;
```

with `virtual void add(const iMatrix& x, iMatrix z) = 0;`